# In Clojure, Is it idiomatically correct to use require ... as rather than use... in the ns macro

Tags: namespaces, clojure

I'm writing a clojure application which is growing from small to medium sized. We're currently importing modules using

```
(ns foo (:use bar))
(fn-in-bar)
```

but I think that switching to

```
(ns foo 
  (:require [bar :as b])) 
(b/fn-in-bar)
```

would help with clarity and code comprehension. Is this a good way to do things? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. The second form is the prefered approach.

There is some discussion related [here](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/ca0101f09147fce4)